# Transform Timestamp inside of the text file

Tags: awk, sed, timestamps

I extract the tables from UDB to local into csv file format. 
After I extract it, my time stamp which shows up multiple times is messed up. I would like to write shell script to update it when it sees that format of timestamp.

> Current Timestamp:

```
2009-06-08-11.15.45.589225
```

> Desired Timestamp:

```
2009-06-08 11:15:45.589225
```

I tried to use `sed` and `awk` commands, but it is a little bit hard to identify current timestamp from the file.

Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps this is something that would be better corrected at the database query stage? see for example [DB2 Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320918/db2-date-format)

Comment: If `sed 's/-/ /3'` isn't all you need then [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output that shows the strings you want to affect (and any you don't) in context within lines.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -Ei 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})/\1 \2:\3:\4/' file
```

---

`([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})` finds the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS` and captures `YYYY-MM-DD` and `HH`.`MM`.`SS`

`/\1 \2:\3:\4/` replaces the whole pattern (YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS) with the captured patterns (YYYY-MM-DD) (HH) (MM) (SS) and replacing then the dash for a space and the dot for `:`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```bsh
sed -Ei 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{6})/\1 \2:\3:\4.\5/g' filename
```

Parentheses split time stamp into 5 groups, so \1 is replaced by 2009, \2 by 06, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works exactly I wanted do. :D

Comment: I think our answers are identical hehe

Answer (score 0):

```bash
tr -c '0-9' '[\n*]' | paste -d '-- ::.'  - - - - - - -
```

This replaces all non-digits from the input with newlines, and then creates output that contains seven fields using `paste` with the delimiters specified using the `-d` option, in turn.

Testing:

```bash
$ echo '2009-06-08-11.15.45.589225' | tr -c '0-9' '[\n*]' | paste -d '-- ::.'  - - - - - - -
2009-06-08 11:15:45.589225
```

```bash
$ cat file
2009-06-08-11.15.45.589225
2009-07-09-11.15.45.222222
2009-08-10-11.15.45.333333
$ tr -c '0-9' '[\n*]' <file | paste -d '-- ::.'  - - - - - - -
2009-06-08 11:15:45.589225
2009-07-09 11:15:45.222222
2009-08-10 11:15:45.333333
```